# Check the database for a specific variable in a table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi can you check a database for a variable in a specific table and if it already exist it will deny the entry.

quick edit sorry :(
I have a database with tables with the same attributes(id,lastname,etc)
they all have the same set of it but in different tables they have different datas on it.

Ex. table1 has "1" as an Id and Table 2 has "2" on an id  and so on.

Im Wondering if for example im going to check if the ID has already a "2" set on a ID on a Table inside a database and if it already has it can deny the table that im creating.

sorry for bad english...

Comment: **WOW**.. *..if so how?*

Comment: You don't need to check for it beforehand to deny the entry. Just set up a unique index.

Comment: Check **ANY TUTORIAL ON THE WEB** and you will see thats exactly what we all do all the time

Comment: I don't get at all your question but, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE id = "2"` will serve you?

Comment: what im wondering is  searching the database for a specifc ID on the many tables in there, and if it finds a match it will not accept my new table because both of their ID is the same.

Comment: @DingoDile I edited answer, hope it's what you are searching

Comment: @SantiGil Yep Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not so much information in your question to provide a nice answer,

but take a look at [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html) and [this link](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/unique.php), maybe it can help you.

There is a UNIQUE constraint to guarantee what you say. If you insert a value wich already exists, it is denied.

**After you edit:**

You can get all your tables of the database with `SHOW TABLES` instruction. Take a look at [this doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html). You can call them all with a pattern, and use the `LIKE` clause.

Then you just have to iterate over this tables. This would be something like

```
for (String table : myTables) {
  if ( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id = "2" ) > 0 )
  then return deny;
}
return accept;
```